# Simple arithmetic challenge function with limited attempts

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, for-loop

Recently began studying Javascript, trying to read out of *Javascript: The Definitive Guide* and *Eloquent Javascript*, while going off on my own to experiment with things in order to really etch them in my memory. I thought a good way to get my head around arithmetic operations and conditional statements, I'd build a series of little games based around each Math operator, and began with addition.

```
function beginAdditionChallenge() {
    var x = Math.ceiling(Math.random()*100);
    alert(x);
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var a = Number(prompt("Provide the first addend.", ""));
        var b = Number(prompt("Provide the second addend.", ""));
        if (a + b === x) {
            alert("Well done!");
            break;
        }
        else if (a + b !== x && i < 3) {
            alert("Please try again.");
        }
        else {
            alert("Fail.");
        }
    }
}

function initChallenge() {
    var button = document.getElementById("challengeButton");
    button.addEventListener("click", beginAdditionChallenge);
}

window.addEventListener("load", initChallenge);
```

You can see the whole thing thus far on JSFiddle, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qadBc/1/). The idea is that clicking the button generates a random number between 1 and 100, displays it to the user, then prompts them to provide two addends, giving them 3 attempts. If the sum of these addends is equal to the RNG number, it congratulates the user and ends the program. If they do not provide suitable addends, the loop prompts them to try again, until they've hit 3 attempts, at which point the program snarks at them and ends.

I know the event listener is not the failure point here, as when I change beginAdditionChallenge to simply display a test alert, it works, but I don't know what exactly is wrong with the loop I've created.

Comment: `Math.ceiling` should be `Math.ceil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did it correctly. However, `Math.ceiling` isn't a function and should be `Math.ceil`. In addition, your code (in jsfiddle) should be set to `wrap in head`. Why? Because right now you call `initChallenge` when the page loads. However, in your jsfiddle example, the code runs `onLoad` so the load event never gets called. Essentially, you're adding a load event after the page has loaded.

http://jsfiddle.net/rNn32/

Edit: In addition, you have a for loop that goes up to three. Therefore

```
else if (a + b !== x && i < 3) {
    alert("Please try again.");
}
```

should be

```
else if (a + b !== x && i < 2) {
    alert("Please try again.");
}
```

because when `i === 2`, the user's last chance has ended.

Comment: Thanks! The ceiling/ceil thing was a silly mistake for me to make. I went and fixed both that and the else if statement and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine. Just change:-

```
var x = Math.ceiling(Math.random()*100);
```

to:-

```
var x = Math.ceil(Math.random()*100);
```